# How to create a back up of a google spreadsheet every week?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet which has a lot of people editing it, and it can be interesting to look "back in time" and see the sheet as it was in previous weeks.

I imagine it would be possible to make a copy and rename it after the current day once every week. Perhaps using the javascript editor within google sheets?

I'm hoping someone can give me guidance on this.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Back-Up-Google-Docs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a google apps script to handle the copy, and set it on a weekly timer. Here is a link to get you started: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#copy(String)